# SQL Count returning username of who has asked the most questions

Tags: sql, count

I'm having trouble working out how to do an sql query and wondered if anyone could help. In my application I have users who can ask questions and I would like to implement some functionality to work out who the most active question poster is.

The table structure is as follows:

User:
`UserID` (Primary Key), `Username`

Question: `Question ID` (PK),`UserID`(Foreign Key) `QuestionText`, `DateTime` Asked

What I would like to do is to find out who has asked the most questions then return their username. I'm having trouble finding answers to similar solutions on the internet. All I can do is count the number of questions asked, and the number of questions asked by different users, e.g. total number of questions asked is 9 and total number of users who have posted questions is 2.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: get the count of the number of questions asked by different users and the max out of them all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selects only one question poster who has posted maximumn number of question.
SQL Server

```
SELECT TOP 1 username
FROM
(
Select userid,username,count(*) as numQuestion
From user u
inner join question q
on u.userid=q.userid
Group by userid,username
)Z
order by numQuestion desc
```

MySql

```
SELECT  username
FROM
(
Select userid,username,count(*) as numQuestion
From user u
inner join question q
on u.userid=q.userid
Group by userid,username
)Z
order by numQuestion desc
Limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

or you could also try this:

```
select count(*) as counter,
name from user join question 
on user.id = question.userid group by user.id
order by counter desc limit 1
```

[sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/74468/8)

Comment: Also works, cheers for the help everyone! I'd vote up all of you if my reputation was high enough